# sending multiple values in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

multiple value send **search.php**
send two value search_word and search_word1. but both value is not display

```
var search_word = $("#search_box").val();
var search_word1 = $("#check_id").val();
var dataString = 'search_word='+ search_word;
if(search_word=='')
{
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "include/search.php",
data: dataString,
```

**search.php**

```
   if(isset($_POST['search_word'])){

$serach_word = $_POST['search_word'];
$serach_word1 = $_POST['search_word1'];
    echo "$serach_word<br/>$serach_word1";

}
```

so Please Help.

Comment: where do put the search words to `dataString`?

Comment: i have add. so please what code is write in search.php page

Answer (score 3):

`data` has to be a javascrpt object:

```
data: {
   search_word: search_word,
   search_word1: search_word1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart form David Fregoli answer you can also,send data in query string form,as you are using GET Method

```
 url: "include/search.php?search_word="+search_word+"&search_word1="+search_word1,
```

Comment: 1) Shouldn't there be an '&' character dividing the query strings?
2) What if the value of search_word is 'a&search_word1=b' ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax POST method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "some.php", 
    data: {name: "John", location: "Boston"} 
}).done(
    function(msg) {
        alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
    }
);
```

Comment: i have used this script for single value send.. so i have multiple value send... please help $(".search_button").click(function()
{
 var search_word = $("#search_box").val();
 var dataString = 'search_word='+ search_word;
if(search_word=='')
{
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "include/search.php",
data: dataString,

cache: false,

Comment: Please try below code & check jquery version $(".search_button").click(function() {
         var search_word = $("#search_box").val();
         var dataString = {search_word: "search_word", search_word2: "search_word2"};
         if (search_word == ''){         
         }else {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "include/search.php",
                 data: dataString,
                 cache: false
             }).done(function(msg) {
                 console.log(msg)
             });
         }
 });

Answer (score 0):

```
if(search_word=='')
{
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "include/search.php",
data: { 
         search_word: $("#search_box").val(),
         search_word1 :$("#check_id").val()
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery simplifies the task. The syntax is

```
$.get("include/search.php",{search_word:search_word,search_word1:search_word},function(response)
{
   alert(response);
});
```

For more details visit https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 0):

You can send selected data:

```
var test = 'yes, this is test string';
...
data: {
     testValue: test,
     filter: $('#form').find('#name_filter').val()
}
```

You can even serialize whole form in javascript

```
data: {
     filter: $('#form').serialize();
}
```

and deserialize it in PHP with simple code

```
$values = array();
parse_str($_POST['filter'], $values);
```

And $values will be full of inputs/select/checkbox values :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **$.param(dataString)**

```
 var dataString: {
       search_word: $("#search_box").val(),
       search_word1: $("#check_id").val()
    }

if(dataString)
{
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "include/search.php",
data: $.param(dataString)
});
}
```

In Server:

```
 if(isset($_POST['dataString'])){   
$serach_word = $dataString['search_word'];
$serach_word1 = $dataString['search_word1'];
    echo "$serach_word<br/>$serach_word1";
}
```